# Hoppscotch with Keycloak token generation fails: Unable to get hold of the Generated Token during the Authorization with OAUTH2 and Keycloak

Tags: rest, postman, token, keycloak, hoppscotch

I am trying to generate the token using the authorization in Hoppscoth. During the authorization, I redirect the user to my Keycloak auth URL where they can provide a username & password, after the successful login I want to obtain the token provided by Keycloak and use it for subsequent requests.

I am able to log in but after login when I am redirected to Hopscotch I am unable to get the Token rather the page just reloads, not sure what's happening. But if I use similar authorization in Postman then everything works fine. Can you please let me know how can I get hold of the token and use it in my request?

Following is my Authorization tab from Hoppscotsch where I am trying to redirect the user to Keycloak page and making them to login:

[image]

After the successful login, I just returned back to the Hoppscotch page and did not get the token or anything:

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or do I need to do aynthing extra to access the token and make the request.

Note:

1. I have already installed the google chrome extension.
2. I also tried with proxy setting from settings.